# I keep getting an error when using the fetch method, dataSource.fetch() that shows `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):` in console

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using a tool called sanity to store my data and use CRUD functions. Everything went well so far, I even stored some fake data to test the tool, but when I tried to use the following method:

```
useEffect(async () => {
        await sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "featured"] {
            ...,
          restaurant[]-> {
            ...,
          dish[]->,
            type-> {
              name
            },
          }, 
        }`).then((data) => {
            setFeaturedCategories(data);
        });
    }, []);
```

It keeps showing this `error:  ERROR  Error: URLSearchParams.set is not implemented.`

I'm using react-native version 0.70.5, as for packages other than react/react-native ones.
I'm using:

`"@sanity/client": "^5.2.2", sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",`

I've tried adding async and await as shown in the code snippet. Still haven't solved anything as the data is still not being received. I've got two more errors:

1)
`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):`

2)

```
Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
```

3. I've added a try-catch block, and it catches an error that states `[Error: URLSearchParams.set is not implemented]`.

I'm still trying to fix the bug as shown in the code snippet above but it didn't work with me so far.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error, and it is telling you that you need [a catch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) in addition to your then block.

Comment: When I tried using `console.log(fetchedData)` it doesn't show me anything, meaning that I'm not receiving data. I've just added a try-catch block, and there is an error, which states `[Error: URLSearchParams.set is not implemented]`

Comment: Did you manage to solve? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I was following the crash course created by sonny, on youtube. I couldn't fix the problem so I gave up on it.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was installing react-native-url-polyfill  and importing it on your root file or any files that require access to a URL/Uri

1.Install  react-native-url-polyfill

`yarn add react-native-url-polyfill`

OR

`npm install --save react-native-url-polyfill`

2.Import
`import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'`

3.Also,for your image urls ,find the exact property that point to the image asset.

```
import React from 'react'
import { urlFor } from "../sanity";
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'

const CategoryCard = ({imgUrl,title}) => {
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity className="relative mr-2">
      <Image source={{ uri:urlFor(imgUrl.asset._ref).width(200).url()}} className="h-20 w-20 rounded" />
      <Text className="absolute bottom-1 left-1 text-white font-bold ">{title}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default CategoryCard
```